# Custom NSFormatter to accept only numbers

Tags: objective-c

I have searched for an answer and tried a lot of user examples posted at SO, however they do not seem to answer my question.

In the UK the majority or area codes begin with zero, I have a single NSTextField and have created a customer NSNumberFormatter. I want my NSTextField to accept numbers beginning with zero, I dont want to use the NSNumberFormatter Padding option as the length of phone number may very but always start with zero.

```
- (BOOL)isPartialStringValid:(NSString*)partialString newEditingString:(NSString**)newString errorDescription:(NSString**)error {


if (partialString.length <= 0 || [partialString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"This is not a positive integer");
    return NO;
}





return YES; } @end
```

The above example works and allows any number to be entered of any length but will always removes the leading zero upon moving focus away from the NSTextField.

Example numbers:
01202
01134
01103111345

How can I stop the leading zero being removed?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Is the formatter a subclass of `NSFormatter` or `NSNumberFormatter`? Did you implement `getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:`?

Comment: Sorry its a subclass of NSNumberFormatter. I havent looked into getObjectValue, but i will take a look now.

Comment: First of all, a phone number is not really a number, it's a `String`. Using `NSNumberFormatter` is a very bad idea then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at a library to manage phone numbers such as 
[libPhoneNumber-iOS](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS) it's got most of this covered. Granted it maybe overkill if you're just looking at working with UK numbers.

I could copy the code here, but it probably more efficient to check out the framework. It's been around for years and years now so it well tested and I've used it many times when working for o2 in their apps. If you don't decide to use it, just look through the code, you'll find your answer there.

I see you're looking for mac you [can do it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/libphonenumber-discuss/Np9DI6vRdAs) but it's effort

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I have taken a look at the link you provided and it seems all IOS related.

Comment: Ah yes, yes it is. Been a while since I did any Objective-C on mac or iOS, but I see the issue. Nevertheless you should be able to find some help there regarding and how to handle the formatting. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: @JulieVrellaku I updated my answer with some assistance for mac. Still not perfect it's a well used library